# Laravel, Vue - "You may need an appropriate loader" for template tags

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, vue-loader

I am currently building a web application using Laravel and Vue. The error that I am getting is for all the components that I have.

```
ERROR in ./resources/assets/js/components/App 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <template>
|     <div id="layout-wrapper">
|         <app-topbar></app-topbar>
 @ ./resources/assets/js/app.js 6:0-35 41:11-14
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/style.scss
```

the App.vue file looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div id="layout-wrapper">
        <app-topbar></app-topbar>
        <app-menu></app-menu>

        <div class="main-content">
            <div class="page-content">
                <router-view></router-view>
                <app-footer></app-footer>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import AppTopbar from './_partials/AppTopbar'
    import AppMenu from './_partials/AppMenu'
    import AppFooter from './_partials/AppFooter'
    import Users from './users/Users'
    import Dashboard from './dashboard/Dashboard'

    export default {
        components: {
            'app-topbar': AppTopbar,
            'app-menu': AppMenu,
            'app-footer': AppFooter,
            Users,
            Dashboard,
        },
        beforeMount() {
            axios.get('/metadata')
                .then(response => {
                    window.Laravel = {
                        response: response,
                        current_year: response.current_year,
                        csrf: response.csrf,
                        asset(path){
                            return this.response.asset+'/'+path;
                        },
                        trans(text){
                            return this.response.trans[text];
                        },
                        route(name){
                            return this.response.base_url+'/'+this.response.routes[name];
                        }
                    };
                });
        },
    }
</script>
```

From the error, I understand that the problem is that <template></template> tags are not being parsed. From what I found out I need the vue-loader and vue-template-compiler dependencies for them. I have already installed those, however, I still keep getting these errors.
I also found that trying the older version (current 15.x.x , older 14.x.x) of vue-loader could help, but it did not.

My versions are:
laravel 8.12.3
npm 6.14.4
package.json dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
        "sass": "^1.29.0",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "vue": "^2.6.12",
        "vue-loader": "^14.2.4",
        "vue-router": "^3.4.9"
    }
```

Since I am not skilled in Vue, I understand that I did something wrong. However, I have not found solutions online. So, I would like to ask for your help.

---

Update:
Since Laravel has a pre-configured webpack.config file then probably, this is what I think I am able to show you.
webpack.mix.js :

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel applications. By default, we are compiling the CSS
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/style.scss', 'public/assets')
    .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')

    .styles([
        // Layout
        'resources/assets/template/system/css/bootstrap.min.css',
        'resources/assets/template/system/css/icons.min.css',
        'resources/assets/template/system/css/app.min.css',
        // Data Table
        'resources/assets/template/system/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css',
        'resources/assets/template/system/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css',
        // Custom
        'public/assets/style.css'
    ], 'public/css/style.min.css')

    .scripts([
        // Layout
        'resources/assets/template/system/js/jquery.min.js',
        'resources/assets/template/system/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js',
        'resources/assets/template/system/js/metisMenu.min.js',
        'resources/assets/template/system/js/simplebar.min.js',
        'resources/assets/template/system/js/waves.min.js',
        'resources/assets/template/system/js/jquery.sparkline.min.js',
        'resources/assets/template/system/js/morris.min.js',
        'resources/assets/template/system/js/raphael.min.js',
        'resources/assets/template/system/js/app.js',
        // Data Tables
        'resources/assets/template/system/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js',
        'resources/assets/template/system/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js',
        'resources/assets/template/system/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js',
        'resources/assets/template/system/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js',
        // Vue
        //'resources/assets/template/system/js/vue.js',
        // Custom
        //'resources/assets/js/vue.js',
        'public/js/app.js',
        'resources/assets/js/script.js'
    ], 'public/js/script.min.js');
```

Comment: Are you using `vue-cli` in your project? If not, is there a webpack config that you can share? Probably the `vue-loader` definition is missing there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Application Laravel 8 + Vue 2.6 versions then please change the code in the

> webpack.mix.js

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        //
    ]);
```

To

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        //
    ]).vue();
```

"you may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type" laravel and vue application error reason >> package.json - "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6" is version 6 or higher.

Answer (score 17):

In Laravel 8 the compilation of assets works in a slightly different way. It will only add vue compilers as a dependency if you declare that you want to compile a vue file in webpack.mix.js.

See what happened to me after doing this: http://prntscr.com/whr7wv

Try changing 
`.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')` 
to 
`.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()` 
and return to post if successful.

Note: consider not using laravel/ui and manually creating app.js

Comment: I eddited webpack.mix.js in root folder and workek for me, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This is what worked for me (Laravel 8 + Vue 2.6). Change the code in the

> webpack.mix.js

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sourceMaps();
```

to

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .vue();
```

then run

> npm update vue-loader

Comment: It's not advisable to copy already accepted answers, adapt them a bit and give them as yourselves. If you have anything to add, you can comment to that answer.

Answer (score -1):

Actually you have not installed ui for vue files in laravel, that's why it does not recognize the template tag in vue file. So run few commands in new terminal:

1. `composer require laravel/ui`
2. `php artisan ui vue`
3. `npm install && npm run dev`